# SPARK SQL SUBSTRING from LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the next SPARK SQL clause:

```
SELECT 
,Element1
,IdGroup
,MaintainId

FROM
(SELECT
    a.Fecha
    ,a.Element1
    ,a.IdGroup
    ,a.MaintainId
    ,b.Per,   b.Per,   b.Per,  b.Per04, b.Per05,   b.Per06

FROM
    table_a a
LEFT JOIN
    table_b b
ON
    a.idcode = b.codeid and a.date = b.date

LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(ARRAY(
    (Per01),(Per02),(Per03),(Per04),(Per05),(Per06)
    )) unp AS Per
WHERE Periodo = 1 
)
```

I need to create a 'Date' column adding the substring of each Per column such an unpivot. For instance, in the row accord to the unpivot of Per06 i need to show '2023-08-01T06:00:00.0000000'

I was trying creating an udf but not get a solution.

I need to create a 'Date' column adding the substring of each Per column such an unpivot. For instance, in the row accord to the unpivot of Per06 i need to show '2023-08-01T06:00:00.0000000'